# Enable and disable org.eclipse.ui.actionSets

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a menu item defined this way:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
<actionSet
   description="My Sample"
   id="MySample.actionSet"
   label="My Sample"
   visible="true">
   <menu
     id="mysample.actionset.menu1"
     label="My Sample">
     <groupMarker
       name="mysample.groupCreatesimilar">
     </groupMarker>
   </menu>
   <action
      class="org.mysample.actions.create.MyCreateCodeAction"
      definitionId="MySample.myCreateCode.command"
      id="MySample.myCreateCode.command"
      label="Create Sample Code"
      menubarPath="mysample.actionset.menu1/mysample.groupMarker2">
    </action>
</actionSet>
</extension>
```

The above actionSet has many other actions. I want the action (menu) "Create Sample Code" to be enabled or disable based on the value of a preference variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the enablement attribute you can write a property tester where you can test your preference variable.

For more on property testers

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Expression_Framework
http://www.robertwloch.net/2011/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-property-testers-with-command-core-expressions/

Also just as a suggestion , you should not use action sets as they are deprecated. Commands should be used. Unless you are in a legacy code :)

Comment: second (external) link not available anymore :(